# How to add log4j.xml path in Ant build.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant, log4j

I have a log4j2.xml file which is not being picked by Ant's build.xml. So, I keep getting the following error message in Eclipse console - 
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. 
My build.xml file is very simple. (*pasted below*) I copied it from one of the examples online.
I have gone through ant documentation and am aware of the    and I have used these to set the log4j2.xml in classpath and have failed.

```
<project name="Learning" default="hello" basedir=".">
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="${src.dir}/lib"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="build"/>

<target name="hello">
 <!-- compile just the basic hello files -->
 <echo> This will have all the basic builds </echo>
 <javac srcdir="{src.dir}" destdir="{build.dir}" 
        includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>
```

Can you please give me a code snippet to add my **Log4j2.xml** file sitting in the **basedir** or the project to the classpath?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, javac does not copy the resources (the directory contains only the compiled classes). However, you can copy them. e.g.:

```xml
<project name="Learning" default="hello" basedir=".">
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="${src.dir}/lib"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="build"/>

<target name="hello">
 <echo>Copy non-java resources</echo>
 <copy todir="{build.dir}" overwrite="true">
  <fileset dir="{src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
 </copy>
 <!-- compile just the basic hello files -->
 <echo> This will have all the basic builds </echo>
 <javac srcdir="{src.dir}" destdir="{build.dir}" 
        includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>
```

See more in [*Copy Task*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).

Comment: This did not help. I still see this error. **StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.**